# ¿Como comunicar labels de forms sin generar mas ventanas en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Gente que tal

Vengo con este caso en el cual requiero mandar un dato de una label de una form a otra form que ya esta abierta sin generar nuevas ventanas. Quiero evitar eso ultimo para que la computadora no genere mucho esfuerzo en el programa espero y puedan ayudarme. Les dejo los códigos que hacen cada uno les recuerdo que ambos forms estan abiertos y no deseo que se generen mas ventanas. La Form2 es la que manda el dato y la Form1 la recibe.

```
Form1:        private void Label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCore.Text = Vinculacion.Text;
        datet.Text = fecha.Text;
        button3.PerformClick();
    }


        Form2: private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main over = new Main();
        over.Vinculacion.Text = label1.Text;
        over.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partamos de la base que en el codigo que nos muestras no se recibe nada, ya que mencionas que `Form2` envia a `Form1` pero estas instanciando `Main`, ademas asignas un Textbox no un Label

Si quieres pasar un dato debes tener la instancia del mismo, y exponer funcionalidad `public` para realizar acciones, no se deberia acceder directo a los controles

Entonces desde el Form1 expones una propiedad que recibira el dato

```
public class Form1
{

   public string Vinculacion { get; set; }

   public void Form1_Load(...)
   {
      txtCore.Text = this.Vinculacion;
   }

}
```

desde el Form2 asignas esa propiedad

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Vinculacion = label1.Text;

    form1.ShowDialog();
}
```

cuando se muestre con el ShowDialog() el form ejecutara el Load y asignara el valor

Comment: pero eso no generaría abrir otra ventana?

Comment: no, porque estas abriendo el form como modal, no se si entendi el sentido de comunicacion de las ventanas, cual es padre de cual otra, pero si vas a enviar datos de una ventana hija a una padre la tecnica cambia completamente

Comment: Bueno te resumo estimado Leandro. El que considero yo form padre es el Form2 este verifica una huella de la base de datos y al hacerlo manda la id a un label al hacerlo genera ese perform click que vez y ese comando hace que la form1 (hijo) cambia el texto de la label Vinculacion y despues genera el evento de text change que lo que hara sera mandar al textbox txtCore su texto

Comment: para que envias el valor a un label si despues generas un evento textchange. Si desde el Form2 abres el Form1 como modal no podras generar una nueva instancia hasta tanto no lo cierres, por lo tanto usar el new en este caso es correcto

Comment: Estimado Leandro. Segui el meto y afirmo que acorto menos comandos pero como dije creo una tercer ventana y es lo que quiero evitar el programa inicia con ambas Forms abiertas y no deseo que se generen mas

Comment: lo que explicas no es posible, como accedes al Form2 para abrir el Form1 si se abre como modal? ests usando el ShowDialog() no se puede abrir mas de una ventana

Comment: Estimado Leandro. Ya verifique y tenia un error al momento de cargar los formularios gracias por tu ayuda ya quedo todo perfecto